# An exercise about compact operat0r

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $A \in \mathfrak{B}(H)$ and $H$ is a Hilbert space, $AT=TA$ for every compact operator $T$, show that $A$ is a multiple of the identity operator.

I don't know what is "multiple of the identity operator" .

*Help? Thank you advance!*

Answer (score 4):

For $x,y \in H$, consider the compact operator
$$
\Theta_{x,y}(z) := \langle z,x\rangle y
$$
If $A\Theta_{x,y} = \Theta_{x,y}A$ for all $x,y\in H$, we have
$$
\langle z,x\rangle A(y) = \langle A(z),x\rangle y \quad\forall x,y,z\in H
$$
Taking $z = x$ non-zero, we have $A(y) = \alpha y$ for all $y\in H$ where
$$
\alpha = \frac{\langle A(x),x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle} 
$$
In other words, $A = \alpha I$

Answer (score 1):

This means the identity $Id:H\to H$, $x\mapsto Id(x)=x$, multiplied by a constant $\alpha$, thus $\alpha\cdot Id$. Note that the factor $\alpha$ may be smaller than $1$ in this generalized use of "multiple".